# Como limpar o vetor nome de modo que ele não fique com resto das strings anteriores

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int condicao;

    cin >> condicao; //Determina o tamanho do vetor //


    while(condicao != 0){

        char nome[100];

        for(int iniciar = 0;iniciar < condicao;iniciar++){

            cin >> nome[iniciar];

        }


        for (int i = condicao - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            cout << nome[i];

        }

        cout << endl;
        cin >> condicao;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Como faço para limpar o Vetor,visto que ao digitar uma nova cadeia de charteres a cadeia anteriormente escrita permaneceu.Por exemplo,eu digito a cadeia "abacate" e o retorno é "etacaba". Retomando,quando insiro uma cadeia,chamada "casa",o retorno é etaasac,ou seja,há a permanência da cadeia anterior,sendo notada pelos três últimos charteres.

Comment: Você quer ler 100 strings, é isso? OU quer ler uma string com 100 caracteres?

Comment: Nós estamos falando do seu código, se nem você sabe o que ele tem que fazer não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Ele vai imprimir a cadeia,digitada pelo usuário, de trás para frente...

Comment: O que é esse `parada`?

Comment: É o que determina o tamanho do Vetor.

Comment: São 100 strings com 100 charteres.

Comment: Você tem que decidir o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

O código é complicado demais e mistura coisas do C que não é o ideal. Use uma `string` mesmo e aí tudo fica muito simples. Veja:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nome;
    cin >> nome;
    for (int i = nome.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << nome[i];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/rzKj1v). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rfzjebeq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Inverse.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar usar o [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) para copiar o fim de cadeia em todas as posições.

```
memset(nome,'\0', 100);
```

Comment: Obrigado,mas consegui resolver.